# SQL базы. В чем различия между ними?

Tags: sql

**PostgreSQL, MySQL, SQLite, Oracle**. В чем между ними *принципиальная* разница. В каких проектах применяется каждая из них. Можно ли оценить с позиции лучше/хуже. Что стоит почитать на эту тему чтобы разобраться. 
И какую из баз лучше выбрать для:
 - блога
 - браузерной игры

Comment: между разными БД такая же разница как между разными летательными средствами: самолетом вертолетом и дельтапланом. как и у летательных апаратов у них одинаковое предназначение.
пока-что все что вас должно заботить, это их доступность (бесплатная/платная). во время изучения sql нет смысла заморачиватся по поводу выбора БД, - выбирайте ту с которой планируете работать в ближайшем будущем

Comment: Для браузерки ИМХО лучше NoSQL =) ( как и для блога xDDD )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Принципиальная разница в скорости и типизации...Насчёт скорости - есть базы которые к примеру быстрей делают выборку , а другие быстрей делают добавление. И нужно думать какая база будет более удобней и быстрей работать под ваш проект. Вам ближе я думаю будет SQLite и MySQL.

Все написанное выше ИМХО. =)

Comment: так какие конкретно быстрее делают выборку быстрее например?

Answer (score 0):

Между Oracle RDBMS и прочими отличие - в лицензии: коммерческая в первом и свободно распространяемые в остальных случаях. Хотя после приобретения MySQL и для них есть теперь коммерческая лицензия.

Comment: > после приобретения MySQL

а если быть точным, то после проеобретения Sun (компания которой принадлежали права на MySQL)